# How do I display the distance on each result?

Tags: laravel, distance

I'm trying to display the distance on each result. I have the latitude and longitude in an addresses table which is joined to the venues table as a 1 to 1.

I've managed to do it so that I have all the distances in an array but when I try and just add them to the venue it just takes the last one in the list. If I wrap a foreach around them then it shows all the distances for every venue.

My controller code

```
public function venues(Request $request)
    {
        $types = DB::table('types')
            ->join('venues', 'venues.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
            ->join('icons', 'types.icon_id', '=', 'icons.id')
            ->where('venues.is_approved', '=', 1)
            ->select('types.*', 'icons.*')
            ->groupBy('types.id')
            ->get();

        $type = $request->query('type');

        if ($type) {
            $venues = Venue::whereHas('type', function (Builder $query) use ($type) {
                $query->whereIn('name', $type);

            })->where('is_approved', '=', 1)->get();
        } else {
            $venues = Venue::where('is_approved', '=', '1')->get();
        }

        if (auth()->user()->address) {
            foreach ($venues as $venue) {
                $earthRadius = '3959';
                $latFrom = deg2rad(auth()->user()->address->address_latitude);
                $lonFrom = deg2rad(auth()->user()->address->address_longitude);
                $latTo = deg2rad($venue->address->address_latitude);
                $lonTo = deg2rad($venue->address->address_longitude);

                $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
                $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

                $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
                        cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
                $distance[] = $angle * $earthRadius;
            }
        } else {
            $distance = '';
        }

        return view('venue.venues', compact('venues', 'types', 'distance'));
    }
```

My Blade code

```
@foreach ($venues as $venue)
                <div class="venue-card">
                    <a href="{{ url('venue/' . $venue->id .'/'. str_replace(' ', '-', $venue->name)) }}">
                        @if (!$venue->photos->count() == 0)
                            @foreach ($venue->photos->take(1) as $photo)
                                <div class="main_image" style="background-image: url({{ asset('/uploads/venues/thumbnails/'.$photo->image_url)}});"></div>
                            @endforeach
                        @else
                            <div class="main_image noimage" style="background-image: url({{ asset('/assets/images/no-photos.svg')}});"></div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="venue-overview">
                            @if ($venue->type->icon_id)
                                <img class="icon" src="{{ asset($venue->type->icon->icon_url) }}">
                            @endif
                            <span> {{$venue->type->name}}</span>
                            <h3>{{$venue->name}}</h3>
                            <p>{{$venue->description}}</p>
                                @if (!$distance == '')
                                        <p><span>{{round($distance, 0)}}</span> miles from your address</p>
                                @endif
                                @auth
                                    <div class="fav_venue">
                                        <favorite
                                                :venue={{ $venue->id }}
                                                        :favorited={{ $venue->favorited() ? 'true' : 'false' }}
                                        ></favorite>
                                    </div>
                                @endauth
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

I've probably come at this the wrong way but any help on how I can adapt this to show the correct distance on the venue will be a massive help.

Answer (score 0):

So after some hours of playing around i've done this which works alright for now:

```
if (auth()->user()->address) {
            foreach ($venues as $key => $venue) {
                $earthRadius = '3959';
                $latFrom = deg2rad(auth()->user()->address->address_latitude);
                $lonFrom = deg2rad(auth()->user()->address->address_longitude);
                $latTo = deg2rad($venue->address->address_latitude);
                $lonTo = deg2rad($venue->address->address_longitude);

                $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
                $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

                $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
                        cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
                $venue->distance = $angle * $earthRadius;
            }
        } else {
            $venues->distance = '';
        }

        $venues = $venues->sortBy('distance');

        $venues->values()->all();
```